# Multiple subtraction raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, differences

For each year from 1951 to 2021 I have two rasters: one precipitation (P) and the other evapotranspiration (E).

I want to do P minus E for each year--so I would like one output of the subtraction (P-E) for 1951, another for 1952, etc.

Is there an automatic way to do this without doing it manually with raster calculator for each year?

Comment: Exactly how are the rasters named?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute raster calculator in [batch](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html#the-batch-processing-interface):

> All algorithms (including models) can be executed as a batch process.
> That is, they can be executed using not just a single set of inputs,
> but several of them, executing the algorithm as many times as needed.
> This is useful when processing large amounts of data, since it is not
> necessary to launch the algorithm many times from the toolbox.